# Xamarin Forms Global variable updates slower than code

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I am using the following code in my App.xaml.cs:

```
public static int agentId;
public static List<Agent> agents;

public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    loadingAgents += onLoadingAgents;
    LoadAgentList();

    MainPage = new MainPage();
}

private event EventHandler loadingAgents = delegate { };
private async void onLoadingAgents(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Agents = await RestService.GetAgents();
}
private void LoadAgentList()
{
    loadingAgents(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

public static int AgentId
{
    get
    {
        return agentId;
    }
    set
    {
        agentId = value;
    }
}

public static List<Agent> Agents
{
    get
    {
        if (agents == null)
        {
            agents = new List<Agent>();
        }
        return agents;
    }
    set
    {
        agents = value;
        AgentId = Agents.Min(x => x.Id);
    }
}
```

Now what this simply should do is the following:

1. On startup, it collects all the Agents from a webcall and puts it in a `List<Agent> Agents`
2. Once the `List<Agent> Agents` is set, it sets the AgentId to the minimum `Id` of the `Agents` list

The problem is that in the ViewModel of the MainPage I use those variables that are supposed to be set, but the code of the ViewModel is faster than the code that needs to update the variables.

How can I wait for the variables to finish before hitting this line: `MainPage = new MainPage();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First i don't think it is necessary to use `private event EventHandler loadingAgents`.Then you get `Agents` is an asynchronous operation,so `MainPage = new MainPage();` has been executed when the method is called(at this time, the Agents may be null).And in general we don't call asynchronous tasks in the constructor to get the data,you could do it in the `OnStart()` method.

You could try to change like below :

```
public App()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

protected async override void OnStart()
{
   Agents = await RestService.GetAgents();
   MainPage = new MainPage();
}
```